# Updating string array from NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have a variable

```
var savedSearchItems: [String] {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: keySavedSearchItems) ?? []
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(savedSearchItems, forKeyPath: keySavedSearchItems)
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way to update my array?

```
case .saveSearchItem(let item):
        var temp = st.savedSearchItems
        print(temp) //always prints "[]"
        temp.append(item)
        st.savedSearchItems = temp
```

Answer (score 2):

The setter in your method causes an inifinite loop. The correct syntax is

```
var savedSearchItems: [String] {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: keySavedSearchItems) ?? []
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: keySavedSearchItems)
    }
}
```

**Never** use `setValue:forKey(Path)` with `UserDefaults`

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.
It was just inattention with setValue:forKeyPath().
But even if I use: UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: keySavedSearchItems) it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then the issue must be somewhere else.